# Container color almost transparent in BoxDecoration with a predefined color function

Tags: flutter, dart

The following code works fine to get the right container color. However, when I want to use the _green function replacing `Color(0xff0c9869)` in the `BoxDecoration` widget, the color turns out to be very pale/transparent.

It seems like the same solution, but the result is totally different, anyone knows why?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final _green = Color(0xff0c9869);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
      Container(
        height: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xff0c9869),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(35),
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [Text('Hi'), Icon(Icons.account_circle)],
        ),
      )
    ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no difference. Is it possible to attach a picture of what is happening ? @ZKK

Comment: @AdelB-Lahlouh after i put the _green = Color(0xff0c9869); inside the   Widget build(BuildContext context) { problem solved!